# Javascript - Replace items in array/object with new items

Tags: javascript

There are two arrays.

```
data = [["hi","0"],["hello","1"],["world","2"]]

dataNumbers = ["0","2","1"]
```

How can I replace the 0,1,2 in data with the values in dataNumbers?

After replacement,

```
data = [["hi","0"],["hello","2"],["world","1"]]
```

And in here,

```
{"data":[["hi","0"],["hello","1"],["world","2"]],"dataNumbers":["0","2","1"]}
```

How do I replace them the numbers in data with dataNumbers?

After replacement,

```
{"data":[["hi","0"],["hello","2"],["world","1"]],"dataNumbers":["0","2","1"]}
```

Comment: you should write what you want data to look like after the replacement

Comment: So what is the end goal of this operation? `[["hi","0"],["hello","2"],["world","1"]]`

Comment: I am using react-native to do drag/drop/reorder and save a list. The order was important for storing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `map()` function for both of these cases.

```js
let data = [["hi","0"],["hello","1"],["world","2"]];
let dataNumbers = ["0","2","1"];

let newData = data.map(function(item,index){
  item[1] = dataNumbers[index];
  return item;
  });
console.log(newData);

let obj = {"data":[["hi","0"],["hello","1"],["world","2"]],"dataNumbers":["0","2","1"]};
obj.data = obj.data.map(function(item,index){
  item[1] = obj.dataNumbers[index];
  return item;
  });
  console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to achieve something like this?

```js
var data = [
  ["hi", "0"],
  ["hello", "1"],
  ["world", "2"]
];
var dataNumbers = ["0", "2", "1"];

const IDX_DESIRED_NUM = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i][IDX_DESIRED_NUM] = dataNumbers[i];
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

```js
var data = [["hi","0"],["hello","1"],["world","2"]];

var dataNumbers = ["0","2","1"]

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

  data[i][1]=dataNumbers;
  
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the target array and assign the value of source array at the same index.

```js
var object = { data: [["hi", "0"], ["hello", "1"], ["world", "2"]], dataNumbers: ["0", "2", "1"] };

object.data.forEach((a, i) => a[1] = object.dataNumbers[i]);

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```